# Convert Enrichlist to Dataframe

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, bayesian-networks

Is their a way to convert an enrichlist from CBNplot into a dataframe, so I can use the the function `bngeneplotCustom` ?

https://github.com/noriakis/CBNplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the 'information' from an enrichlist as a dataframe using e.g.

```r
e_list <- enrichKO(data)
enrichlist_df <- e_list@result
```

NB. the `bngeneplotCustom()` function appears to require the enrichlist object, not just a dataframe of the results.